# PostgreSQL : NOT IN clause causes "too many columns" error

Tags: postgresql, in-clause

I am using postgreSQL 10 and I try to create a rather complex query.

Here it is

```
select clothes_id , true as iscon 
 from archive
 where 
 customer_id = 101 and 
 clothes_id <> 1 and 
 shoes_id is null  and 
 clothes_id is not null and 
clothes_id not in 
( select shoes_id, clothes_id from archive where customer_id in
  ( select customer_id from archive where customer_id <> 101 and clothes_id = 1 )  
)
```

This query gives the error

```
> ERROR:  subquery has too many columns LINE 5:                
> clothes_id not in ( select shoes_id, clo...
>                                         ^ SQL state: 42601 Character: 147
```

How do I fix this?

If you want to know what this query tries to do, in order to debug, read below

The archive is a table that connects customers, shoes and clothes.

This query tries to select all the times a customer ordered specific clothes and then checks that against another set of subqueries. Those subqueries check if any other customer ordered the same clothes. If s/he did, then the query will not eventually return that clothes.

So, having an instance of the archive table like so

```
clothes - customer - shoes
1          101       2
1          101       6
24         101       null
24         3         2
```

The query will not return the clothes 24, because customer 3 also ordered them. So, it will return nothing.

Thanks

Comment: The error is because your subquery is returning two columns when it should only be returning one. If I'm understanding what you're looking for, though, there are bigger issues and you need to do two separate subqueries (one for clothes, one for shoes) and restructure your boolean a little by adding parentheses as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

`IN` matches the left side to the right side so there needs to be only one column in the result set on the right side. You can do a UNION if you want.

```
clothes_id not in 
  ( select shoes_id from archive ...
    union
    select clothes_id from archive ...
```

Or you can do two `IN`s

```
clothes_id not in 
  ( select shoes_id from archive ...
and clothes_id not in
  ( select clothes_id from archive ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The IN clause is missing one more column comparison - `shoes_id`

```
select clothes_id, true as iscon 
 from archive
 where 
 customer_id = 101 and 
 clothes_id <> 1 and 
 shoes_id is null  and 
 clothes_id is not null and 
 (shoes_id, clothes_id) not in 
 (select shoes_id, clothes_id from archive where customer_id in
     (select customer_id from archive where customer_id <> 101 and clothes_id = 1)  
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

you not in clause don't macth the number and of column you should reduce the number of column in select

```
    select clothes_id , true as iscon 
     from archive
     where 
     customer_id = 101 and 
     clothes_id <> 1 and 
     shoes_id is null  and 
     clothes_id is not null and 
     clothes_id not in 
    ( select  clothes_id from archive where customer_id in
      ( select customer_id from archive where customer_id <> 101 and clothes_id = 1 )  
    )
```

or you could try using a tuple   for compare the NOT IN clause result

```
    select clothes_id , true as iscon 
     from archive
     where 
     customer_id = 101 and 
     clothes_id <> 1 and 
     shoes_id is null  and 
     clothes_id is not null and 
    (shoes_id, clothes_id) not in 
    ( select shoes_id, clothes_id from archive where customer_id in
      ( select customer_id from archive where customer_id <> 101 and clothes_id = 1 )  
    )
```